# Dynamically widening a div based on content

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://gyazo.com/133a13a773c56740f6d0d7ea6aca643c)

My current code is [this](https://codepen.io/Robinlemon/pen/QgdJJW)

The issue is that I want the balance div to stretch as the balance gets bigger, as currently it exceeds its bounds and is shifted underneath, other small issues about appearance are present too!

```css
</style><style type="text/less">
@HeaderHeight: 150px;
@HeaderMargin: @HeaderHeight / 4;
@Color: #ff003c;

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
    div.header {
        width: 100%;
        height: @HeaderHeight;
        background: #333;
        
        div.profile-right {
            float: right;
            
            img.avatar {
                float: right;
                margin: @HeaderMargin @HeaderMargin @HeaderMargin 10px;
                height: @HeaderHeight / 2;
                width: @HeaderHeight / 2;
                border-radius: 100%;
            }
            
            div.data {
                float: right;
                display: table;
                height: @HeaderHeight;
                color: #FFF;
                
                div.container {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    
                    span.username {
                        font-size: 1.2em;
                        display: block;
                    }
                    
                    div.info {
                        width: 100%;
                        font-size: 1.2em;
                        display: block;
                        
                        i.sign.out.icon {
                            margin: 0;
                            font-size: 1.2em;
                            line-height: 1em;
                            float: right;
                            width: 15%;
                        }
                        
                        div.balance {
                            border-width: 10px;
                            font-size: 1.2em;
                            border: 2px @Color solid;
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            width: 75%;
                            
                            span.funds {
                                font-size: 1em;
                                text-align: left;
                                margin-left: 4px;
                            }
                            
                            i.add.icon {
                                width: initial !important;
                                height: initial !important;
                                font-size: 1em;
                                float: right;
                                margin: 1px 5px;
                                color: #000 !important;
                                background-color: @Color !important;
                                padding: 1px !important;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    div.page-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(~"100%" - @HeaderHeight);
        background: black;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
    <div class="profile-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/184x184" class="avatar">
        <div class="data">
            <div class="container">
                <span class="username">Username</span>
                <div class="info">
                    <i class="sign out icon"></i>
                    <div class="balance">
                        <span class="funds">$<span class="value">4.20</span></span>
                        <i class="circular inverted add icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page-content"></div>
```

Comment: Are you able to edit the HTML?

Comment: please learn how to use css `flexbox` and then if that doesn't help, come back and ask again..

Comment: @WizardCoder yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have managed to achieve what you want using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. The plus icon is set to a fixed width but if the value gets larger it will expand the div.

I have also removed some of the floats and switched them to `display:inline-block` so they can be aligned vertically. I have changed the HTML very slightly by adding some additional wrappers.

You might want to implement the changes in to your main stylesheet because currently I am just overriding your styles at the bottom of the stylesheet.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwyXMM

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block;` so that your content fits properly in the balance div.

```css
</style><style type="text/less">
@HeaderHeight: 150px;
@HeaderMargin: @HeaderHeight / 4;
@Color: #ff003c;

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
    div.header {
        width: 100%;
        height: @HeaderHeight;
        background: #333;
        
        div.profile-right {
            float: right;
            
            img.avatar {
                float: right;
                margin: @HeaderMargin @HeaderMargin @HeaderMargin 10px;
                height: @HeaderHeight / 2;
                width: @HeaderHeight / 2;
                border-radius: 100%;
            }
            
            div.data {
                float: right;
                display: table;
                height: @HeaderHeight;
                color: #FFF;
                
                
                
                div.container {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    width:200px;
                    
                    
                    span.username {
                        font-size: 1.2em;
                        display: block;
                    }
                    
                    div.info {
                        width: 100%;
                        font-size: 1.2em;
                        display: inline-block;
                        
                        
                        
                        i.sign.out.icon {
                            margin: 0;
                            font-size: 1.2em;
                            line-height: 1em;
                            float: right;
                            width: 15%;
                        }
                        
                        div.balance {
                            border-width: 10px;
                            font-size: 1.2em;
                            border: 2px @Color solid;
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            width: 100%;
                            display:inline-block;
                            
                          
                        
                        span.value{
                          font-size:1em;
                          width:70%;
                        }
                            span.funds {
                                font-size: 1em;
                                text-align: left;
                                margin-left: 4px;
                            }
                            
                            i.add.icon {
                                width: 25% !important;
                                height: initial !important;
                                font-size: 1em;
                                float:right;
                                margin: 1px 5px;
                                color: #000 !important;
                                background-color: @Color !important;
                                padding: 1px !important;
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    div.page-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(~"100%" - @HeaderHeight);
        background: black;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
    <div class="profile-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/184x184" class="avatar">
        <div class="data">
            <div class="container">
                <span class="username">Username</span>
                <div class="info">
                   
                    <div class="balance">
                    <i class="sign out icon"></i>
                        <span class="funds">$<span class="value">5333.20</span></span>
                        <i class="circular inverted add icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page-content"></div>
```

I have also moved (i.sign.out.icon) sign out icon within the balance div and made width of balance div to 100% so that everything stays on same line and fits properly.

Comment: Sure, but the plus symbol isn't on the right, can I put a padding-right on the balance, then have the plus symbol be there?

Comment: I tried that already, but the downside is that the exit button now isn't on the right; see how much of a pain it is........

Comment: I have moved (i.sign.out.icon) sign out icon within the balance div and made width of balance div to 100% so that everything stays on same line and fits properly. Check it out now

Comment: but the sign out icon shouldn't be inside the div.balance